# Edit Linked Library, bpy.ops.render.opengl.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, linked-data

I have linked file and I'm trying to use Edit Linked Library Addon via script to change the material
like this:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['obj_name']
bpy.ops.object.edit_linked()
bpy.data.objects['obj_name'].active_material=bpy.data.materials['Material2']
bpy.ops.wm.return_to_original()

bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "/../testing.png"
bpy.ops.render.opengl(animation=False, write_still=True, view_context=True)
```

but it gives the error:

> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.render.opengl.poll() failed, context is incorrect

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
I inspected the [source code](https://github.com/blender/blender-addons/blob/master/object_edit_linked.py) and turns out the problem stems from:

```
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=settings["original_file"])
```

The explanation given [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/244539/131649) as:

> When you load a new file with open_mainfile the current file gets
> thrown out. That includes the context of the Python script you're
> running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took an alternative approach, it's a little hacky but it gets the job done:

```
import bpy,subprocess

file_path="/path/to/file.blend"

code="import bpy;bpy.data.objects['obj_name'].active_material=bpy.data.materials[',material_name'];bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)"
output = subprocess.check_output(f'blender "{file_path}" -b --python-expr "{code}"', shell=True)
bpy.data.libraries["Dummy.blend"].reload()
```